# Rails group_by beginning_of_week to get ISO weeks instead of standard weeks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a report using group_by to break out orders for a month by week. This works perfectly fine using rails beginning_of_week method but it breaks up weeks for a month using standard instead of ISO weeks.

**groups orders by week**

```
orders = orders.group_by {|x| x.order_date.beginning_of_week(start_day = :monday)}
```

**loop in view**

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>price</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% orders.each do |week, items| %>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
         Orders week of <%= week.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %> - <%= (week + 4).strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>    
        </th>
      </tr> 
      <% items.each do |weekitem| %> 
        <tr>
          <td><%= weekitem.item_number %></td>
          <td><%= weekitem.price %></td> 
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I thought I could chain cweek like below but it returns an error.

```
orders = orders.group_by {|x| x.order_date.beginning_of_week.cweek(start_day = :monday)}
```

Considering my example how would I group_by ISO weeks instead of standard? Is there any way to switch that using beginning_of_week method or is there another way this has to be done?

Comment: Can't you call `cweek` on the date itself? Like `x.order_date.cweek`?

Comment: Hi eirikir. That does work thank you, but how would I get the date from the week number? Sorry if this is an obvious question I'm still learning rails

Comment: Im not sure how to upvote your comment as the solution. Thank you very much. I think I can figure out how to get the date from the week number.